# issue coming up with right regex_extract in bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, extract

I wanted to do regex_extract on the below data in the column. I wanted values of veer_id

{"accountNo":"3er35d4","veer_Id":"63-21-193-2","Insights":[{"per":"4eetdfyefds","categoryInsights":[{"category":"rt_scores","insightsdf":[{"name":"###","value":{"isNewRcmd":"" }}]}]}]} `

I tried to do regex_extract on  veer_id but unable to parse it correctly . I'm open to better options too.

I tried json_scalar_extract but in not able to parse it correctly. any suggestions please?

```
`r'veer_id:(\d+)')`

veer_id:([{^"}]+)

JSON_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(c.log, r'[\[\]]', ''),  '$.veer_id' )
```

Comment: I tried the following and it worked:

JSON_VALUE(log,'$.veer_id') and it worked for me